# Did the tail of Siding Spring distort communication between Mars, and Earth?

Tags: communication, comet, mars-orbiter-mission, risk-management, maven

[This article](http://www.thehindu.com/sci-tech/science/im-safe-and-sound-tweets-mom-after-comet-sighting/article6520803.ece) writes to say

> There was an hour’s communication blackout during the comet’s fly-by ...

What happened here? Did the tail of Siding Spring serve to block/distort communication between Mars, and Earth?

Comment: I'm adding the MAVEN tag in a few places, I deleted Mars to make room, feel free to roll back. MAVEN's hiding from Siding Spring debris mentioned here: https://www.nature.com/news/hydrogen-cloud-blows-off-mars-1.16156 (found [here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40490/12102))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Communications blackout was because they phased orbits of Mars orbiters to be "behind Mars" when at greatest risk of cometary dust impacts. [MOM phased its orbit too](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2014/1009-mars-orbiter-mission-shifts.html) and so did NASA's / ESA's Mars orbiters. Depending on their orbit, this communications blackout should last roughly 40 minutes. With MOM's highly elliptical and over three Earth days long (nearly 3 Martian days) orbit, I wouldn't be too surprised if its time "behind Mars" was a bit longer than that.

According to [NASA](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?release=2014-244):

> The comet's nucleus will miss Mars by about 82,000 miles (132,000
>   kilometers), shedding material hurtling at about 35 miles (56
>   kilometers) per second, relative to Mars and Mars-orbiting spacecraft.
>   At that velocity, even the smallest particle -- estimated to be about
>   one-fiftieth of an inch (half a millimeter) across -- could cause
>   significant damage to a spacecraft.

So that's over Solar system's escape velocity at Martian orbital altitude and adding particles' velocity to orbiters' own orbital speed even the tiniest particles would carry huge kinetic potential ($E_\text{k} =\tfrac{1}{2} mv^2$, notice the square of velocity $v$) and it was simply more prudent to employ a few simple and affordable measures than *risk it*. Phasing orbits was one of threat mitigation options and they took it.

[image]

<sup>A slide on spacecraft mitigation plans shared during the [CIOC](http://www.cometcampaign.org/) (Coordinated Investigations Of Comets) [Comet Siding Spring and Its Close Approach to Mars: Observer's Workshop](http://www.cometcampaign.org/workshop), August 15, 2014, during the [Session 1: Setting the Stage; Spacecraft Observations](http://new.livestream.com/viewnow/comets/videos/58947411)</sup>

NASA dubbed this ["Duck & Cover"](http://www.nasa.gov/jpl/mars/pia18611/) on social media, but it's just one of the risk management options really.

[image]

You can read a bit more in a related thread [What risk management options are available for Mars orbiters and rovers to mitigate threat of impacting with Siding Spring cometary debris?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3111/what-risk-management-options-are-available-for-mars-orbiters-and-rovers-to-mitig)